# Align text center below a SVG circle?

Tags: html, svg

Suppose I have the following SVG:

```
<g transform="translate(300, 300)">
    <circle r="5px"></circle>
    <text>My Label</text>
</g>
```

I need the label to be centered below the circle. Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option:

```
<g transform="translate(300, 300)">
    <circle r="5px"></circle>
    <text baseline-shift="-20px" text-anchor="middle">My Label</text>
</g>
```

The -20px depends on your font size, and maybe someone has a relative way of doing the drop, but the `text-anchor="middle"` will center the text.

Comment: This works perfect. The text will be a constant size defined in px, so a relative solution (although it would be nice) is not required. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the `em` unit to give you a value based on the font-size. I don't think `baseline-shift` is supported in all browsers so I'd recommend using `y` or `dy` instead. In the example given this would be `<text y="5" dy="1em" text-anchor="middle">My Label</text>`, since 5 is the radius of the circle, which we then need to offset by the current font-size to get the text to be under the circle.

Comment: Does it take zooming into account? Text and circle disperse on zoom in.